# find median of two sorted arrays - I get stackoverflow exception

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, median, stack-overflow

The problem is given `two sorted Arrays`, find the `median` of the two in `O(log n)`. merging the sorted arrays and finding the median (at n/2) should work.but that is `O(n)` time I guess and it requires an auxillary storage. I found this [pseudocode](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~kalpakis/courses/441-sp03/hws/hw4-sol.pdf)(problem 2 in the pdf). when I implement that code, I get `stackoverflow exception`. Here is my code:

```c
public static int quickMedian(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int startArr1, int endArr1, int startArr2, int endArr2){  
        int m1=(endArr1-startArr1)/2;
        int m2=(endArr2-startArr2)/2;
        if (arr1[m1]==arr2[m2])
            return arr1[m1];
        if (arr1[m1]<arr2[m2])
            return quickMedian(arr1, arr2, m1, endArr1, startArr2, m2);
        else 
            return quickMedian(arr1, arr2, startArr1, m1, m2, endArr2);
    }

public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] arr1={1,3,5,7};
        int[] arr2={2,4,6,8};
        int[] arr3={1,2,4,6,8,10,11};
        System.out.println(quickMedian(arr1, arr2, 0, arr1.length-1, 0, arr2.length-1));
    }
```

I need help fixing `stackoverflow exception` and make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the input your run this on? I don't understand how this method could work if the elements in `arr1` are disjoint from those in `arr2`. Also, won't the median be at `(start+end)/2` not `(end-start)/2`?

Comment: @AndyG: The input I run is given in main method above. the pseudocode in the link above calculates median that way.

Comment: then my original point stands. There is no shared element in the arrays so how could your base case `if (arr1[m1]==arr2[m2])` ever return true?

Comment: @AndyG: yes are correct. how could one fix this, to get the median of arbitrary inputs.for example, the median of {1,3,5,7,9} and {2,4,6,8} will be 5 although 5 is not common to both

Comment: Why `m1=(endArr1-startArr1)/2` and not `m1=(endArr1+startArr1)/2`?

Comment: Just a side remark for the sake of accuracy: calculating `m1` and `m2` PDF rounds up while your code rounds down.

Comment: @AlexD; would that rounding either way (up or down) makes a difference here, I thought it does not. I guess it is `m1=(endArr1-startArr1)/2`, because when you call recursive method, you treat a range of array as new Array and so the index corresponds to that array..

Comment: Re rounding - my remark is just for completeness, we get stackoverflow in both cases. Regarding '-' vs '+', I'm not so sure though. If `startArr1==6` and `endArr1==8`, I would expect that in the first `if` we check `arr1[7]`, not `arr1[1]`. Or not?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the ending condition

```
if (arr1[m1]==arr2[m2])
        return arr1[m1];
```

because it allows the algorithm to run indefinitely, if median value is not present in both arrays. Therefore `quickMedian()` method is called over and over again, until you run out of space in stack.

**EDIT :**

I've analysed the pseudocode a bit further and I can contently say that the algorithm is fundamentally flawed. The main point of the algorithm is to take two arrays, divide them into half, discard halves that won't contain the median and then repeat for the rest of arrays.

Problem with this approach is, that when we discard halves of arrays, that don't contain the median, we are left with two arrays that contain the median, but it is not guaranteed, that the median of original arrays and halved ones will be the same. If one array contains more elements than the other, more elements will be discarded from one array and the median of new arrays may shift.

```
a1 = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}    median = 6
a2 = {5}                  median = 5

// median of a1 + a2 is 5
```

After first step:

```
a3 = {1,2,3,4}            median = 3
a4 = {5}                  median = 5

// median of a3 + a4 is 3
```

the median of `a3 + a4` will now be 3, because three elements higher than 5 have been dropped, but no lower element. It is true, that the median of original arrays is *in* two new arrays, but it is not the same element as *median* of new arrays. Therefore this recursive method will not work, no matter how many patches and fixes are applied. Therefore I would also suggest considering merging of two arrays.

Comment: yes, I thought about it, the pseudocode in the above link just describes what I did..not sure how to fix this to get the median of two sorted arrays.

Comment: I found several solutions that uses this approach but not exactly. so the recursive way here might work, but as you pointed out the base case is really bad. here is one such link; http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

While you've correctly implemented the code in the solution PDF, the solution is bad (for arbitrary input).

You've got some short arrays, so why not walk through what's happening?

*main:*

```
quickMedian({1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, 0, 3, 0, 3)
```

*quickMedian:* (1)

```
m1 = (3 - 0) / 2 = 1
m2 = (3 - 0) / 2 = 1
if (3 == 4)...// false
if (3 < 4) quickMedian({1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, 1, 3, 0, 1)
else...// unreached
```

*quickMedian:* (2)

```
m1 = (3 - 1) / 2 = 1
m2 = (1 - 0) / 2 = 0
if (3 == 2)...// false
if (3 < 2)...// false
else quickMedian({1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

*quickMedian:* (3)

```
m1 = (1 - 1) / 2 = 0
m2 = (1 - 0) / 2 = 0
if (1 == 2)...// false
if (1 < 2) quickMedian({1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, 0, 1, 0, 0)
else...// unreached
```

*quickMedian:* (4)

```
m1 = (1 - 0) / 2 = 0
m2 = (0 - 0) / 2 = 0
if (1 == 2)...// false
if (1 < 2) quickMedian({1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, 0, 1, 0, 0)
else...// unreached
```

As you can see, the call to `quickMedian` in the 4th iteration is identical to the one in the 3rd iteration. This is where the result breaks down.

---

Given the problem "here's two sorted lists, find the median value between both of them," my first response would be to merge the lists and find the median of the whole. Merging two sorted lists is O(n), however, not O(log n) as requested by the problem.

Comment: Merge sort is O(n log n), but merging two already sorted lists is O(n).

Comment: how could one fix this, to get the median of arbitrary inputs.for example, the median of `{1,3,5,7,9} and {2,4,6,8}` will be `5` although 5 is not common to both

Comment: @user1988876, As Warlord says in his answer, the termination condition is bad. Consider the fact that in the third iteration in my walkthrough above, the start _and_ end index of `arr2` is 0. From that point onwards, _no matter what_, `arr2[0]` is going to be the value you're comparing against. What can you glean from that?

Comment: @BrianS: I totally understand your point. I am just asking for a termination condition that will make this work, for an example case I gave above in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is `O((logN)^2)` algorithm for median searching :-

> 1. take mid of the biggest array among two
> 2. Find the index i of number greater  than mid in other array using binary search
> 3. If no of elements s upto mid & i exceed the current kth element to be found then do median search on those parts recursively
> 4. else do median search for knew = kold - s  element on remaining subarrays.
> 5. If only 1 array is left then find the kth element in O(1).

**Pseudo Code :-**

```
void medianSearch(arr1,arr2,s1,s2,h1,h2,k) {

  len1 = h1-s1+1;
  len2 = h2-s2+1;

  if(len1<=0||len2<=0) {

     if(len2<=0) {
           return(arr1[s1+k-1]);
     }

     else return(arr2[s2+k-1]);
  }

  if(len1>len2) {

     int mid = (s1+h1)/2
     int i = binSearch(arr2,s2,h2,arr1[mid])
     int size = i+mid-s1+2;
     if(size>=k) {
         return(medianSearch(arr1,arr2,s1,s2,mid,i,k))
     }
     else {

        return(medianSearch(arr1,arr2,mid+1,i+1,h1,h2,k-size));
     }
  }

  else {

      // Use similar logic as first case. 
  }

}

Call:- medianSearch(arr1,arr2,0,0,M-1,N-1,(M+N)/2)
```

**Time Complexity : -**

> Each iteration reduces atleast one array to half of its orignal size.
>   Each iteration takes O(logN). Total iterations will be O(logN) hence
>   T(N) = O((logN)^2)